# Подскажите, почему появляется эта ошибка(ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Я сделал проверку на пустой список в функции mousePressEvent(),но там ли я это сделал и правильно ли?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow, QHBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPainterPath, QPen, QColor, QBrush, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize, QPoint, QRectF

areas = [
    [(540, 420), (620, 300), (370, 140), (250, 390)],
    [(60, 30), (550, 310), (50, 520)],
    [(200, 500), (370, 390), (170, 200)]]

EDIT_AREA = True

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.widthApp, self.heightApp = 700, 550
        self.pos = QPoint()
        self.pos_list = []
        self.color = QColor(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.brush = QBrush(self.color)
        self.padding = 40

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(200, 200))
        self.setGeometry(600, 300, self.width(), self.height())
        self.setWindowTitle('Traj')
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        self.qp = QPainter()
        self.qp.begin(self)
        self.qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.drawLine(self.qp)

    def map_point(self, x, y):
        x_min, y_min = None, None
        x_max, y_max = None, None

        for trajectory in areas:
            for x_, y_ in trajectory:
                if (x_min is not None) and (y_min is not None):
                    x_min = min(x_, x_min)
                    y_min = min(y_, y_min)
                else:
                    x_min, y_min = x_, y_

            for x_, y_ in trajectory:
                if (x_max is not None) and (y_max is not None):
                    x_max = max(x_, x_max)
                    y_max = max(y_, y_max)
                else:
                    x_max, y_max = x_, y_

        x = (x - x_min)
        y = (y - y_min)

        return x, y

    def drawLine(self, qp):
        path = QPainterPath()

        def draw_area(area):
            if EDIT_AREA:
                path = QPainterPath()
                qp.setPen(QPen(Qt.black))
                for x, y in area:
                    x, y = self.map_point(x, y)
                    self.qp.drawEllipse(x-3, y-3, 6, 6)
                qp.drawPath(path)

        for area in areas:
            draw_area(area)

        qp.drawPath(path)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.index_point = []
        self.index_point_area = []
        self.items = []
        self.mouse_point = (event.x(), event.y())

        def dist_squared(p1, p2):
            return (p1[0] - p2[0]) ** 2 + (p1[1] - p2[1]) ** 2

        for idx, area in enumerate(areas):
            for idx_p, (x, y) in enumerate(area):
                x_screen, y_screen = self.map_point(x, y)
                if abs(x_screen - event.x()) ** 2 + abs(y_screen - event.y()) ** 2 > 25 ** 2:
                    continue
                else:
                    self.items.append((idx, idx_p, x_screen, y_screen))
                    # print("self.items:", self.items)

        # print("self.items_finaly:", self.items)
        nearest_point = min(self.items, key=lambda x: dist_squared(self.mouse_point, x[2:]))
        print("nearest_point:", nearest_point)
        self.index_point_area.append(nearest_point[0])
        print("self.index_point_area:", self.index_point_area)
        self.index_point.append(nearest_point[1])
        print("self.index_point:", self.index_point)
        # print("index_point:", self.index_point_area[0], self.index_point[0])

        if not nearest_point:
            nearest_point = min(self.items, key=lambda x: dist_squared(self.mouse_point, x[2:]))
            self.index_point_area.append(nearest_point[0])
            self.index_point.append(nearest_point[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста минимальный пример, демонстририющий вашу проблему.

Comment: хотя бы на какой строке ошибка?

Comment: @Bogdan после функции dist_squared(): . В строке с nearest_point.

Comment: Походу получается, что `self.items` тоже пустой.

Comment: @Jazzis проверил через `print()`. Он не пустой. Проверил и в `else` и перед `nearest_point = min()`.

Answer (score 2):

Запустил ваш код. Ошибка возникает в 100 строке.

И если раскомментировать строку с принтом перед ней, то прекрасно видно, что в момент ошибки `self.items` у вас таки пустой.

Легко проверить, что `self.items.append` в вашем коде не выполняется, если только не тыкать прямо в одну из точек.

Comment: Заметил в чем ошибка. Как и предполагал до этого, я не тот список проверял.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде работает:

```
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.index_point = []
        self.index_point_area = []
        self.items = []
        self.mouse_point = (event.x(), event.y())

        for idx, area in enumerate(areas):
            for idx_p, (x, y) in enumerate(area):
                x_screen, y_screen = self.map_point(x, y)
                if abs(x_screen - event.x()) ** 2 + abs(y_screen - event.y()) ** 2 > 25 ** 2:
                    continue
                else:
                    self.items.append((idx, idx_p, x_screen, y_screen))

            print("x_screen", x_screen)
            print("y_screen", y_screen)

        def dist_squared(p1, p2):
            return (p1[0] - p2[0]) ** 2 + (p1[1] - p2[1]) ** 2

        if self.items:
            nearest_point = min(self.items, key=lambda x: dist_squared(self.mouse_point, x[2:]))
            self.index_point_area.append(nearest_point[0])
            self.index_point.append(nearest_point[1])
        # print("index_point:", self.index_point_area[0], self.index_point[0])

        if not self.items:
            pass
```